# Decrypt automatic created drupal url

Tags: 7, hooks, uri

In my project url encryption and decryption are compolsary,so help me How to decrypt drupal automatically created url (eg: "q=content/testpage")?

Comment: Once you've had a chance to edit the question and clarify what it is you're asking, please flag for re-opening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do, but if I understood right you can do this with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) modules, so:

1. Go to *[your-domain-name]/admin/config/search/clean-urls* and make sure that Clean URLs is enabled
2. Install and enable [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and go to *[your-domain-name]/admin/config/search/path/patterns*, there you can fill in settings for your paths
3. Install and enable [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module, no additional configuration is required

URLs will be updated on cron run.